# Push entire subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

I have an array this the format below. Trying to push multiple entire subarrays (starting with A-) fulfilling a condition to a new array and keep the array format. Have no success with the code below.

Array:

```
{"#VER": {
    "A-1": {
        "verdatum": "2016-07-08",
        "vertext": "1073, Almi",
        "trans": [{
            "account": "1510",
            "amount": "52500.00"
        }, {
            "account": "3010",
            "amount": "-42000.00"
        }, {
            "account": "2611",
            "amount": "-10500.00"
        }]
    },
    "A-2": {
        "verdatum": "2016-07-08",
        "vertext": "1074, Text",
        "trans": [{
            "account": "1510",
            "amount": "15000.00"
        }, {
            "account": "3010",
            "amount": "-12000.00"
        }, {
            "account": "2611",
            "amount": "-3000.00"
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Code so far, but changes format of array

```
var newarray = [];
$.each(array["#VER"], function(i, item) {
if (condition for subarray) {
    newarray.push(i,item);  
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with an object here, not an array. This code should work:

```
var data = { ... };                         // your original data object
var filteredData = filterData(data);

function filterData(data) {
  var verData = data['#VER'];
  var filteredVerData = {};

  $.each(verData, function(key, value) {
    if(value.vertext === '1073, Almi') {    // your condition
      filteredVerData[key] = value;
    }
  });

  return {
    '#VER': filteredVerData
  };
}
```

But if you have many root keys like '#VER' and you need to filter all of them, you'd need to write one more loop:

```
var data = { ... };                         // your original data object
var filteredData = filterData(data);

function filterData(data) {
  var result = {};

  $.each(data, function(verKey, verData) {
    $.each(verData, function(aKey, aData) {
      if(aData.vertext === '1073, Almi') {  // your condition
        result[verKey] = result[verKey] || {};
        result[verKey][aKey] = aData;
      }
    });
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: In real life the if statement is a complex filter and multiple subarrays will be pushed

Comment: Of course, thanks! Wanted to complicate with push...don't know why